# Odoo v11: Automatically upgrade all modules mentioned in __manifest.py

Tags: python, odoo-11

I have created a startup project `myapp_main` for all my Odoo projects.

Whenever I install this main project; Odoo installs all `depends` modules (x, y, z)

Here's manifest.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
    'name': 'myapp_main',
    'version': '1.0',
    'summary': 'MyApp main project',
    'depends': ['x',
                'y',
                'z'
                ],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
}
```

This approach works fine for fresh installation but doesn't work when we are upgrading. I expect that all dependent modules should also get auto-upgraded whenever I upgrade the main project.

Has anyone achieved this? Any ideas please.

Comment: What distribution (if any) do you use? What installation routine do you use?

Comment: @Dschoni I am using Community edition

Comment: By default it is happening.

Comment: @KevalMehta No. it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The Odoo system automatically updates all *dependent* modules, i.e. those modules, that depend on updated modules.

The `depends` clause lists all modules that your module depends on.  That means that if you update any of `x`, `y` or `z`, your module will also be automatically updated, but not the other way around.

If you want to update `x`, `y` and `z` whenever your module is updated, you need to add your module in the `depends` list of `x`, `y` and `z`. This may not be trivial/possible, if you are not their maintainer, to modify their manifest file.
Sometimes, an (otherwise empty) package is used to group a whole set of related modules together this way.

If `x`, `y` and `z` do not technically depend on your module in the first place, there seems to be no reason to update them.